# No reputation from suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, suggested-edits

According to [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

> You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through
>   suggested edits

and on Stack Overflow I have earned 882 reputation from suggested edits (according to [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)). This should mean that I can get reputation from 59 more edits ((1000-882)/2) as long as I do not hit 2000 reputation. But in the last couple of days (since Mar 8 around 18:00) I have not gotten reputation from my suggested edits that has been accepted. To see this, compare [my suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789593/n-n?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and [my reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789593/n-n?tab=reputation). Am I getting something wrong or is this a bug?

As [suggested by Dennis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125311/163868) it might be that I already got 1000 reputation from suggested edits. In that case [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) is clearly wrong in reporting that I have earned only 882 reputation from suggested edits.

Comment: It is possible that you have suggested edits on posts that were deleted. These would no longer count towards your reputation, but may count towards the count of 500 suggested edits.

Comment: @Oded That would make 59 deleted posts that I suggested edits for. Is that likely? Anyway, that should be reflected in the reputation stats so that one may understand what is up.

Comment: Indeed, I believe that's correct on both points.

Comment: Check the "show removed posts" and sift through your reputation pages looking for "-2" entries.

Comment: We'are aware of this...the capping issue is solved but there's some missing rep I'm trying to see if I can restore here...will answer once that's done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There were 2 bugs here, one fixed 2 days ago one fixed just a few moments ago.

First, post deletions weren't immediately affecting your rep as they should have (it was getting skewed) - that was fixed 2 days ago.

Second, the "do you have 1,000 rep from suggested edits?" check wasn't paying attention to deleted posts, so it was giving a false positive and stopped awarding early (if you reached 1000, but then lost some due to post deletions, it still *said* 1,000).

Going forward, you **can** re-cap to 1,000 if a post gets deleted.  We'll auto-recalc and restore rep from what *were* post-1000-rep suggested edits when deletions happen.  If you still have room before reaching 1,000 after that, future suggestions will continue to award +2 until you reach it.

Also, with the next build reputation for all pre-reputation-from-suggested-edits...edits will be awarded (it's easier to do this than not to do it).  And those few users who capped at 1,000 but then lost some rep due to post deletions will get any post-1,000-rep-suggestion approval +2 rep entries back up to 1,000 again (think daily rep cap, up to 200 in a day, but 1,000 for all time, same behavior).

If any of the above doesn't make sense, you're probably not crazy and I've looked at too many numbers today.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can make sense of most of it! So in the next build these changes are pushed to all SX sites?

Comment: @N.N. - correct, the next build of meta will run a bit of SQL back-filling those votes, and affected users will have a bit of a rep impact from the additional +2 entries within 5 minutes after that.

Answer (score 5):

As Oded suspected, you have already more than 500 suggested edits approved.

According to your edit stats (you can see them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/218607)):

> N.N. had 518 edit suggestions approved, and 66 edit suggestions rejected.

Comment: That doesn't explain why he has less than 1000 rep for suggested edits though.

Comment: @BenBrocka: N.N. earned `+2` rep for the first 500 suggested edits, so he earned `1000` rep for them. The fact that he lost part of those points doesn't seem to be taken into account.

Comment: There still is something wrong in http://stackoverflow.com/reputation saying "earned 882 reputation from suggested edits".

Comment: It means you had 441 edits approved and 59 rejected when you hit 500 suggested edits.

Comment: @Dennis According to [Nick Craver's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125287/no-reputation-from-suggested-edits#comment338211_125287) there *is* missing reputation.