# Today I got 2 reputation and I am not able to find from where I had get.Is it bug or a bonus point?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

On date 12-03-2012 My reputation on Stackoverflow was 4738 but when I checked today my reputation increase by 2 points. I had try to check from where I had get those 2 repo but I am not able to see any entry in the reputation graph.

So it is a bug or any bonus points that stackoverflow is giving ?

Here is the my [repo link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630668/dharmendra?tab=reputation)

Comment: Bonus points for your regal avatar. I salute you, Kind Sir

Comment: I have not seen any rule that give me two extra points because of some avatar.I think you are kidding me. is it?

Comment: Yes every day if I find any unformated question or answer I am doing proper format. But after some repo limit when I edit some question or answer I am not getting any repo.

Comment: The same just happened to me. Very noticeable, as I had 4498 yesterday, and now I have 4500. I'm not complaining, but it feels strange.

Comment: Oh, I found it in my rep history I think. I've got '0' for 'Feb 22', so I guess a -2 points was reverted since.

Comment: I *think* it could be made slightly clearer, with a 'revert' style/text.

Comment: Yeah I think same may be its revert the downvote.

Comment: I still don't get why people care about a ~0.0004% change in their reputation...

Comment: @TomWijsman - it's not the number change per se, but when the number changes inexplicably that bothers people.  One likes to think that rep is not arbitrary, but rather tied directly to actions.  When it changes with no corresponding action, that's disturbing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You made a suggested edit that previously didn't award a +2, before we started awarding +2 for approved edits.  As part of [fixing missing votes for the people who 1,000-capped on suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125287/no-reputation-from-suggested-edits/125411#125411), it was far easier to backfill for everyone, and act as if we always awarded +2.  Since that only **awarded** people a small amount of rep, I didn't think anyone would mind.

Comment: Ohh I see, So +2 repo is for suggested edit. But after some points when I was able to edit question and answer, I am not getting +2 for edit.

Comment: @Dharmendra - Yep, that is correct - we just credited some suggested edit effort people made here that wasn't previously rewarded.

Comment: Okay I get you. Thanks for your answer and knowledge.

Comment: Ah, so that must be what was the matter with my rep. Thanks (both for the answer and for the tiny rep boost)! :)

Comment: *I didn't think anyone would mind* - you should have known better - people here worship rep and are freaking out from any change. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that a user had downvoted one of your posts and this was either reversed or the user was removed (which I think removes their downvotes)...

Comment: Thanks for your response. But if some one down-vote me then my reputation will show me that -2 repo is decrease and if any user downvote me and also remove that downvote then how can I get 2 extra points ?

Comment: @Dharmendra lets pretend a user downvoted you a year ago...so you would have at some point received -2 rep. Now, move to a year later and that user decides to "un" downvote you...this means that you need to get your -2 rep back...which is effectively a plus 2..but not really, it's just "not a -2"...but because this might have happened a long time ago, you wouldn't see it as activity recently

Comment: Yeah this can be happened. But is there any way that I can check for which question or answer I have get +2 reverse back ?